# how do I configure Oracle Net Listener on a server with two network connections

Tags: oracle

I have a server that I have virtualized and as such it has two network connections, one to simulate a network between several virtual machines and the other to connect to the host physical network. when this server starts, oracle net listener does not start automatically. My understanding of this issue is that there is a conflict in host address configuration in my `.ora` file seeing as during initial install, net config assistant sets it up with a host address. Can someone advise me on how to correctly configure this Listener to have it startup automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have static ips you can configure them all in the listener.ora file:

> ```
> LISTENER=
>   (DESCRIPTION=
>     (ADDRESS_LIST=
>       (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521))
>       (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.0.1)(PORT=1521))
>       (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.0.2)(PORT=1521))
>       (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=extproc1521))))
> ```

If you don't know the IPs or Hostname, you can also leave out the HOST part (this is undocumented as far as I know) this will result in listening on any:

> ```
> (DESCRIPTION =
>   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(PORT = 1521))
> )
> ```

Comment: Thanks Dieter for that suggestion, one connection is on static ip and the other is on auto ip config. is it possible to combine option 2 of your suggestions with option 1?